# C# Selected Implementation of Interface

Tags: c#

Is there a way to select methods to be implemented in an interface?  I think in Java they have adapter to only select what method you want.

Comment: What happens with the members you don't implement?

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. An Interface requires that all methods be implemented.

Comment: example I have method1 and method2 in interface1 then i implement interface1 in class1 then i also implement interface1 in class2 but i only need method1 to be implemented. does my question contradict rules in OOP. sorry for a dumb question

Comment: then basically the interface needs to be broken since you have now discovered that it is a generalisation of two other behaviours that are not mutual.  Go for 'good' in 48klocs' answer.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to pick-and-choose what you implement.  You can, however, from good to bad to worse...

good - break the interface up into multiple interfaces - your classes can pick and choose what interfaces they should inherit from based off of what functionality they should provide (your classes can inherit from as many interfaces as you want)

bad - throw a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx)

worse - silently do nothing

Do you have a need to do this or is it curiosity?  It sounds like you're laying the foundation for a very confusing API if you're destroying the value of interfaces.  They define contracts that callers rely on.

Answer (score 4):

The point of an interface is to say **"Hey, anything that implements me is *guaranteed* to have all of the members that I declare!"**

If you want anything other than that, then you don't want an interface, or you want an interface that declares only method1, in your example.